# Azure Storage Account - blobs: Download over Storage Explorer = fast, https+sas over Browser = slow

Tags: performance, storage, account

I have 2 azure storage accounts (normal and premium / both in EU West) using the blob storage. 
The problem occurres on both:

When downloading a file (15GB) using storage explorer (1.9) using azcopy, i get full download speed (up to 30MByte/sec).

When i generate an url+sas within the storage explorer and try to download the file in a browser (chrome, firefox), i only get 2-3 MByte/sec. (same computer and internet connection)

I tried to download over 3 different internet connections and different computers.

Is this a known limitation?
When azcopy advertise an improved transfer-method, where is the bottleneck when downloading with a browser?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Did you find a solution or reason for this ?